# How to install node-sqlite3, but skip the build step and provide my own build of sqlite3?

Tags: node.js, build, node-sqlite3, node-pre-gyp

I am interested in understanding how to install [`node-sqlite3`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/), but provide by own precompiled package of [`sqlite3`](https://sqlite.org/): I just want to install the Node client and skip the build phase entirely during install.

How can I do this?

(*Reasoning: I am going to test the module in multiple environments and have already read countless posts of people having build issues in various environments, so I'd rather manually compile myself.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was looking for a package like this one:

**dblite** on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dblite), [GitHub](https://github.com/WebReflection/dblite)